# Once I put in a screw with a dry wall anchor screw, can I remove the screw and replace the screw without ruining the anchor?

Tags: drywall-anchor

I want to mount plumbing pipe on dry wall as a curtain rod. I have dry wall anchor screws. The style of curtain I have will require me to remove the bracket from the wall to be able to take the curtain down (to wash it). Once I put the screws in with the anchors, can I remove the screws later without ruining the anchors?

Comment: Depends on the anchor. I do have to ask, though...how often you have to wash your curtains?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you are, so while products examples mentioned are sourced in North America, they are widely available under different names.

My first and best idea is to use a rod that doesn't require you to unscrew anything, like this: 
[image: Closet pole sockets]

Next would be hollow wall anchors that unscrew gracefully:
[image: Hollow wall anchors]

Last best would be screw in anchors:
[image: EZ Ancor twist/lock]

(edit to add...) The bad thing about these is that they can come out with the screw if the connection between the drywall isn't great. (In other words, if they're put in badly, they can spin out.) (Thanks to @batsplatsterson for reminding me of this.)

Comment: The hollow wall anchors are a good idea, but the last suggestion , plastic screw in anchors, would not work well.  When you unscrew, the screw will stay in the anchor and the anchor will come out of the wall.  The metal ones are supposed to work better if you have to unscrew, and the sometimes do, sometimes don't.

Comment: Thanks, @batsplatsterson, I'll edit my answer to address the point you raised.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the plastic anchors with small wing bolts.  If you have to remove the pipe again, don't worry about losing the wing part of the bolt since it will drop down inside the wall.  Just use another wing bolt when you reattach the pipe.  There is the added benefit of a superior attachment vs plastic anchors that usually get loose and fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. But, we don't sign our answers; you can put anything you want to tell about yourself in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Use these [toggle anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831) for the best results.

They are the strongest drywall anchors you can find plus They have the added benefit of the  Metal  toggle part having machine threads to except the machine screw so once they’re in place you can undo the screw as many times as you want without affecting the quality of the  holding power. .

Comment: That link shows several different types of anchor. Some of them will tend to fall down inside your wall when the screw is removed...